# C# Regex remove character within the element name only, without replacing the value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

I want to get rid of ':' within the XML elements tags only, using regex in C#.

I am aware that parsing the document is the way to go instead of regex..but it is a legacy project and it uses Regex to replace the XML Document content. Not the ideal method to process XML Document, but nothing I can do about.

I am not good with regular expressions and just can't figure out a way to replace ':' only from the Element Tags and not values...

For example 
`<tag:name> the value with the tag http://www.example.com </tag:name>`

I want to replace : with _ only within the element name and not value. So the outcome should be :

`<tag_name> the value with the tag http://www.example.com </tag_name>`

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
Regex tagRegex = new Regex("<[^>]+>");
yourXML = tagRegex.Replace(yourXML, delegate(Match thisMatch)
{
   return thisMatch.Value.Replace(":", "_");
});
```

Comment: It will actually replace colons appearing anywhere in a start tag, end tag, comment, or processing instruction, in text content if delimited by a CDATA section, and in various places in a DTD - including for example colons in an attribute name or attribute value, colons in a comment, or colons in the URI referring to an external DTD. Yes, you are right - regexes are not the way to do this.

Comment: @mikel, maybe  if you change your needle to something like ```<\s*[^\s=>]+```, it would be more exclusive.  That way it won't match attributes.  You could go a bit further and say it can't start with !, ```<\s*[^!][^\s=>]+```

Answer (score 2):

This needle should do what you want:

`<[^>]*(:)[^>]*>`

The first pattern group will contain the (:) in the tag name.  If you want to do a replacement you can replace `(<[^>]*)(:)([^>]*>)` with `$1_$3` where `$1` and `$3` are sub-patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am afraid it doesn't work as expected. I tried to replace using `Regex.Replace(content, "(<[^>]*)(:)([^>]*>)", "_")`, but it also replaces all the empty tags with '_'

Comment: I believe you want, ```Regex.Replace(content, @"(<[^>]*)(:)([^>]*>)", "$1_$3")```.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Still not perfect though :| My XML file has an element, for example, `<Assets:POS1_filedetails></Assets:POS1_filedetails>`, and that doesn't convert to `<Assets_POS1_file></Assets_POS1_file>`

Comment: frb, that works for me, in .net:  [regex]::replace('<Assets:POS1_filedetails></Assets:POS1_filedetails>','(<[^>]*)(:)([^>]*>)','$1_$3')

Comment: @Sharon, I think it should work there.  If there were *two* or more colons in one tag, it would just replace the last one.  (I don't think that's normal in XML, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the file provided is not a valid XML file, hence the : in element names. But, the solution that mikel provided, worked.